# Is Karma applicable outside of karmabhumi?

Tags: puranas, karma, skanda-purana, phala

In Skanda Purana Bharat desh has been referred to as Karmabhumi which means place where noble deeds are rewarded. So does it mean karmaphala is not reaped outside of Bharat desha ? If it is reaped then why is Bharat desh referred to as Karmabhumi?

Comment: Ishwara is karmaphaladhata. He would give karmas everywhere for all pranis. But Karmabhumi might just mean place good for satkarmas, yajñas and tapas as Rishis tapas shakti is present in bharata through different kshetras.

Answer (score 1):

**What does Karma-bhumi mean?**

**On Bharata**

> The natural traits of the Kurus have been precisely recounted. Now I
> shall mention the features of Bharata. Understand them.

**Vayu Purana I.45.72**

> O excellent Brahmanas, in the sacred centre to the south of the
> southern mountain Himavat, extending from east to west is the Bharata
> sub-continent. It behoves you to listen now to the details of the
> countries in the Bharata Varsa and of the people there.

**Vayu Purana I.45.73–74**

> With its diverse features giving rise to auspicious and inauspicious
> results, this sub-continent is in the middle, to the north of the
> ocean and to the south of the Himavat.

**Vayu Purana I.45.75**

> Since the country (Varsa) is called Bharata the people are Bharatis.
> Since Manu [2] ruled over the people, he is called Bharata.
> Etymologically derived thus the Varsa (country) is called Bharata.

**Vayu Purana I.45.76**

[2] This etymological explanation of ‘Bharata’ attributing its credit to Manu who is called ‘Bharata’ due to his act of maintain (and feeding the people) supersedes the Jaina tradition which attributes it to Bharata, the son of Tirthankara Rishabha

> **It is from here alone that one goes to heaven or attains salvation
> [3].** The middle course - heaven as well as the end, the final
> emancipation - is attained from here. Rituals for human beings are not
> ordained anywhere else on earth.

**Vayu Purana I.45.77**

[3] **Due to this special importance of Bharata, it is called** **Karma-bhumi**.

Basically Bharata is called karma-bhumi because only here people do spiritual practices under the guidance of a Guru and attain moksha. Of course, nowadays, spiritual practices under the guidance of a Guru can be done in many parts of the world and so the entire world is now Karma-bhumi.